# Can't Add to Collection in VB.NET (Duplicate Exception)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, collections

I am using the following code:

```
    Dim questions = db.Tbl_Challenge_Questions.Where(Function(x) x.Quest_Challenge_ID = challengeId)

    Dim answersToQuestions = New Collection

    For Each question As Tbl_Challenge_Question In questions

        Dim questionId = question.Quest_ID
        Dim answer = question.Tbl_Challenge_Question_Answer.Where(Function(x) x.QAns_Question_ID = questionId).FirstOrDefault.QAns_Answer()
        Debug.Print("Quest_ID=" + question.Quest_ID.ToString)
        Debug.Print("answer=" + answer)
        'answersToQuestions.Add(question.Quest_ID, answer)

    Next
```

Which outputs this:

```
Quest_ID=1
answer=True
Quest_ID=2
answer=150 minutes
Quest_ID=3
answer=True
Quest_ID=4
answer=False
Quest_ID=5
answer=Continuing to smoke
```

When I un-comment the line to add to the collection `answersToQuestions.Add(question.Quest_ID, answer)`, it outputs this error:

```
Quest_ID=1
answer=True
Quest_ID=2
answer=150 minutes
Quest_ID=3
answer=True
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
The program '[4948] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**Add failed. Duplicate key value supplied.**

There don't appear to be any duplicates.  How can I add all of these item to my collection?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a strongly typed collection, such as a Dictionary(of Integer, String)?

Comment: what type is `Collection` please supply either the code or link to MSDN

Comment: @Jodrell - I suspect it's [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx) since it's the only one I can find that's a) called `Collection`, b) isn't generic, and c) has an `Add` method accepting multiple parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yep, its obvious. After not using it much, one forgets about the curiosities of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this to see if it works:

```
Dim questions = db.Tbl_Challenge_Questions.Where(Function(x) x.Quest_Challenge_ID = challengeId)

    Dim answersToQuestions = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    For Each question As Tbl_Challenge_Question In questions

        Dim questionId = question.Quest_ID
        Dim answer = question.Tbl_Challenge_Question_Answer.Where(Function(x) x.QAns_Question_ID = questionId).FirstOrDefault.QAns_Answer()
        Debug.Print("Quest_ID=" + question.Quest_ID.ToString)
        Debug.Print("answer=" + answer)
        answersToQuestions.Add(question.Quest_ID, answer)
     Next







    Next
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks.  I am still getting used to the different types of collections in VB.NET.  In my native PHP, there is just one:  `array()` :)

Comment: @user1477388, IMO generally avoid the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace

Comment: It's hard to get a grasp on what functions belong to what namespace, for me.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the Visual Basic specific [`Collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx) class (meant for legacy code bases, really).

Its [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.add.aspx) method expects to be passed `Item`, then `Key`, not `Key` then `Item`:

```
public void Add(
    Object Item,
    string Key,
    Object Before,
    Object After
)
```

You already have a value in there with the Key `True`...

As @Paul Grimshaw recommends, I'd also recommend using a generic type such a [`Dictionary(Of TKey,TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).